# Odoo , Domain, filter date and month

Tags: python, date, filter, odoo

I try to create a filter domain in sale.report as : Month(order_date) = month(current_date) AND Day(order_date) <= Day(current_date).

```
filter string="This Month" domain="[(('date').strftime('%%m'),'=', ((context_today()).strftime('%%m'))),(('date').strftime('%%d'),'&gt;=', ((context_today()).strftime('%%d')))]"/>
```

I have a problem in left side of domain : ('date'), System say: AttributeError: object has no attribute 'strftime'.

try many combination, but response it's same.

Have you an idea ? What is the type of object 'date' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution, sale.report is not a real model, it's a view. For add field, you need to overwrite select method.
so

```
class sale_report(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.report' 

    date_order_month = fields.Char(string='Date Month')
    date_order_day = fields.Char(string='Date Day')


    def _select(self):
        select_str = """
             SELECT min(l.id) as id,
                    l.product_id as product_id,
                    t.uom_id as product_uom,
                    sum(l.product_uom_qty / u.factor * u2.factor) as product_uom_qty,
                    sum(l.product_uom_qty * l.price_unit * (100.0-l.discount) / 100.0) as price_total,
                    count(*) as nbr,
                    s.date_order as date,
                    date_part('month', s.date_order) as date_order_month,
                    date_part('day', s.date_order) as date_order_day,
                    s.date_confirm as date_confirm,
                    s.partner_id as partner_id,
                    s.user_id as user_id,
                    s.company_id as company_id,
                    extract(epoch from avg(date_trunc('day',s.date_confirm)-date_trunc('day',s.create_date)))/(24*60*60)::decimal(16,2) as delay,
                    s.state,
                    t.categ_id as categ_id,
                    s.pricelist_id as pricelist_id,
                    s.project_id as analytic_account_id,
                    s.section_id as section_id
        """
        return select_str
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is example how you can do it. In this example i search for users with write_date (which is datetime) = yesterday.

```
yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 2)
yesterday_beginning = datetime.datetime(yesterday.year, yesterday.month, yesterday.day,0,0,0,0)
yb = yesterday_beginning.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")
today = datetime.datetime.now()
today_beginning = datetime.datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day,0,0,0,0)
tb = today_beginning.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")
self.env['res.users'].search([('write_date','>=',yb),('write_date','<',tb)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take another fields to store order month and day if you want to filter data as you explain.

```
'order_month' : fields.char('Month')
'order_day' : fields.char('Day')
'order_year' : fields.char('Year')
```

Add all these fields in default.

```
'order_month' : lambda *a: str(time.strftime('%m')),
'order_day' : lambda *a: str(time.strftime('%d')),
'order_year' : lambda *a: str(time.strftime('%Y')),
```

Now you can directly add these fields in filtration.

Comment: I think you are reason : left operand cannot be an object, juste a string. 
So i try your proposition but i can't add field in model sale_report. 
Fields are visible in UI in models but not in database
Have you an idea ?

`class sale_report(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.report' 
    
    date_month = fields.Char(string='Date Month')
    date_day = fields.Char(string='Date Day')`

I have not error message.

Comment: Yes on left side of operator there must be a database field name on which you can not apply any function. To update those fields into the database you must update that module.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implementing this via Python code, you can do this in xml like:

```
<filter string="Current Month" domain="[('payment_date','&gt;=',context_today().strftime('%%Y-%%m-01')),('payment_date','&lt;',(context_today()+relativedelta(months=1)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-01'))]"/>

<filter string="Next Month" domain="[('payment_date','&gt;=',(context_today()+relativedelta(months=1)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-01')),('payment_date','&lt;',(context_today()+relativedelta(months=2)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-01'))]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Odoo stores the date as unicode string. You actually need to use the datetime.datetime class.
An example:

`datetime.datetime.strptime(<YOUR DATE>, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime('%%m')`

Comment: This not work. 
I think it's forbidden to use function in left operand of domain in filter

Comment: Store the result of the expression in a new field and you can use it.